# How can i create view using bootstrap in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap, how can i create view  shown in image.a corosel has number of boxes[enter image

Answer (score 0):

Use this template for get the image. You can edit it on top of this structure.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-5">
         <div class="col p-5">Column</div>
         <div class="col p-5">Column</div>
         <div class="col p-5">Column</div>
         <div class="col p-5">Column</div>
         <div class="col p-5">Column</div>
         <div class="col p-5">Column</div>
         <div class="col p-5">Column</div>
         <div class="col p-5">Column</div>
         <div class="col p-5">Column</div>
         <div class="col p-5">Column</div>
     </div>
</div>
```